# True Type Fonts(ttf) not working in css

Tags: html, css, font-face, truetype, google-font-api

I am trying to take my google font api now and make it local but I am running into problems. I am currently using this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans')
```

and i've been researching and saw that I can use "Font-face" with the downloaded ".ttf" file. So I tried using the ttf file but it's not working at all. I tried converting it into "woff" but still no luck. Here is my code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: opensans;
    src: url(../fonts/OpenSans_Regular/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

#ok{

    font-family: opensans;
}
```

Comment: you check that your path is correct relative to to the css file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I pushed it out of the css file using the "../" and reopen the directory

Comment: devtools should show if the font is being fetched. What does that show?

Comment: I checked the devtools and in "Source"  I didn't see the folder for the fonts so I added the "ttf" file in the css directory and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your path might be wrong, remember it's the path from the .css file.

Try to see your navigator's console for errors.

Also, you might need to precise a fallback font and put your font family name into brackets, like this

```
font-family: "opensans", sans-serif;
```

Also, you'll need to include multiple font-formats to ensure browser compatibility. More information here [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Depending on your project requirements you could use the option provided by Google Fonts, and include this in your CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

#ok {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
```

Comment: The path is correct, i took it out of the css file and started from the first directory using "../". And also I want to make it local and not use the google api cause this will be displayed locally not online